# Using retrofit 2 with robospice

Tags: android, retrofit, robospice

I have used retrofit-robospice module in my previous project, it uses retrofit 1.6 .
with the new version of retrofit (retrofit 2), I want to rewrite that module with  retrofit 2 .
 I have heard from some programmers that there is no need to use robospice anymore and you can just use retrofit 2 itself .
the reasons that I use robospice :

1. Listeners
2. Configuration Change Managment
3. async requests
4. caching
5. no memory leaks

so my question is do you recommend using retrofit-robospice module ?

 if yes in which scenarios ?

 and does it worth rewriting that module for retrofit 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO. What you asking here is a subjective opinion of different people. Everyone will just say to use or not to use a retrofit-module. So i'll just be like others. In my experience robospice-retrofit makes an excellent job, and i definitely recommend to use it and i'm using it myself. But again it's just another opinion of another person.

If you're already asking this question then it must be that the scenarios of using Robospice you've got figured out yourself until now. Why would you ask if that's not true. There's an excellent [infographics](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/master/gfx/RoboSpice-InfoGraphics.png) which illustrates the usage better than any words.

And the last one about does it worth to rewrite the module or not. The answer is: "Yes, it is worth the effort". The library itself is an open source project with the code base located on GitHub. Not to mention that by 'rewriting' the module one would save the others from asking that same question again in the future. So instead of asking somebody else to do the work and give it on the silver plate everyone may just do the work by himself and share his work with others. And after that one would be able to tell us was it worth to rewrite the retrofit Robospice module or not.